# How to make this SQL Query with math?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about an sql query or maybe view.

Here are the tables that are involved, i have only typed the relevant fields:

Table 1 Fields:

- ID  (primary, auto increment)
- isWarranty (can be 0 or 1)
- isCounting (can be o or 1)
- status  (can be 1 to 6)

Table 2 Fields:

- main_id (matches ID from Table 1)
- active ( can be 0 or 1)
- amount ( 0-999)
- price  ( 0.00 - 9999.99)
- currency ( 1 or 2)

That i need to do here is, get the sum of prices (amount * price) for the following conditions:

1. isWarranty = 0 and isCounting = 1 and status <6
2. isWarranty = 0 and isCounting = 0 and status <6
3. isWarranty = 1  and status <6

entriey in table 2 that have active = 0 should be ignored and curreny should be right. eg. for case 1 i desire a result like this:
currency 1 = 5000.00 currency 2 = 3000.00

in the end there should be 6 values, one for each currency per case

can this be done by pure sql or does it need to be done in php?

Comment: I believe a simple join with the required where clauses can give you what you desire

Comment: Table 1 status can be 1-6 but conditions only search for > 6? Also not clear on how currency comes into it.

Comment: Sorry the >6 was a typo, it should be <6 !

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how currency comes in to it?

Comment: Lets use the case "isWarranty = 1 and status<6". For this, i need 2 numbers, the sum of the entries where the case is true, and currency is 1, and another one for currency is 2, like group by. the value in the field price is always the "item price", its currency is definded by the field currency, so it would be just a sum of the field price, it would be wrong, since both currencies are mixed up.